# Using Pytube to download videos of a playlist of specific length

Tags: python, pytube

I am trying to download the videos of a YouTube playlist using the PyTube - library. Since the playlists I need have a few thousand videos I want to add the condition that just videos of the length 10s to 1 hour should be downloaded.
So far I can download all videos of a playlist with the following code:

```
from pytube import Playlist

url = 
# url is the url of the YouTube playlist
play_list = Playlist('url')
for video in play_list.videos:
    video.streams.first().download()
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the length of a video from `pytube.YouTube.length`

https://pytube.io/en/latest/api.html#pytube.YouTube.length

```
from pytube import Playlist

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLoROMvodv4rOhcuXMZkNm7j3fVwBBY42z'
play_list = Playlist(url)
for video in play_list.videos:
    if video.length>60*60:  # video.length is in seconds
        continue
    video.streams.first().download()
```

Comment: the line `if video.length>60*60:` makes sure that only videos with a length of more than 1 hour are downloaded?

Comment: nope, if the condition is true, then continue with the next element in the loop/iteration --i.e., skip the rest of the code in the loop. Please do not forget to accept the answer if this solution is acceptable for you.

Comment: Thank you, the continue command was new for me :)